# Issue setting entry_date via channel form

Tags: safecracker, jquery, date

I'm getting a problem with the entry_date field when creating an entry via a channel form.

I have set the following parameters on the channel form:

```
  include_jquery="no"
  include_assets="no"
  datepicker="no"
```

and I am initializing the date picker field myself as I want to set the date format and date range myself:

```
        //init our datepicker setting date range
    $date.datepicker({ minDate: -90, maxDate: "+0D"});

    //set our date format based on locale
    var locale = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    if (locale === "en-US") {
            var dateformat = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
        } 
        else {
            var dateformat = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
        }
        $date.datepicker({dateFormat: dateformat});
```

After submitting the form When I look in the database (exp_channel_titles) it has the correct values for the year, month and day columns but the entry_date column is saving a timestamp that is always a day **behind**.

If I change the channel form to use the native EE implementation of the date picker, i.e set my parameters to :

```
  include_jquery="no"
```

thereby having EE initialize the date picker field then the date is saved correctly but this way I am unable to set the date format or date range.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This likely isn't your specific issue, but you should always submit dates in the same format as your EE date format setting - especially when using ambiguous date formats as you do above. Otherwise EE has no idea what you mean when you submit a date for any date of the month before the 13th (because the first two date segments could reasonably be assumed to be month *or* day).

Comment: That thought occurred to be last night too. The thing is our site is accessed globally, so I don't want to tie users in to a US date format which could be very confusing for non US users. Other than handling a conversion during form submission can you think of any way to let EE know the format before hand?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue, unlikely that someone else will run into it but you never know.

So we migrated our site from 2.7.2 > 2.10.2. During the migration I did a straight copy of the entire exp_member table. However the column structure of this table has diverged across the new versions. My table was missing two columns relating to localization settings (date format & hours). Adding these back in fixed my issue.